# Function parameter with strange charset behavior in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, character-encoding

i have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

function labelValidate($label)
{
    echo mb_detect_encoding($label.'x', 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');

    echo '<br />';

    echo mb_detect_encoding('Rio, coração do Brasil', 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');
}

labelValidate('Rio, coração do Brasil');

?>
```

I get this output:

ISO-8859-1 
UTF-8

Anybody knows why the parameter $label has ISO charset, but the direct echo which i created inside the function has UTF-8 encode?

This is generating a headache to me, because i have to put a utf8_encode in $label var, otherwise i get problematic chars in the output.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you get when you use the strict mode (third parameter)?

Comment: @str I've putted the third parameter (true), but i get the same result.

Comment: *Do not* use Notepad to save PHP code as UTF-8! It will insert 3 extra bytes (the so-called Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of the file, which will be treated as output (which will be invisible on the client, since it corresponds to a zero-width space) and therefore prevents you from using the `header` function. Set Dreamweaver to save as UTF-8 instead, or use some other editor which doesn't force a BOM.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen, You saved my day! Using Notepad the script was generating a invisible output that was crashing the layout, so i downloaded the Notepad++, it has a large options of charset, including the convertion to UTF-8 without BOM. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Marc B and @Michael Madsen, i downloaded Notepad++ (PHP IDE) and converted the file UTF-8 charset without BOM, so all my problems have been resolved. The Dreamweaver was saving some files as ANSI, this was generationg the confusion on PHP.

Many thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

It's about your text editor.

Try to delete both 'Rio, coração do Brasil' strings from code and write it one more time.

Comment: Hi, Piotr! Sorry, but i didn't understand. Write it one more time where?

Comment: @masimao: delete from strings from the script, and then retype them in a utf-8 editor. It's possible that the file was changed in a non-utf8 mode so that one of the two copies of the `Rio` string was actually entered in iso-8859 mode.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski, I've deleted both 'Rio, coração do Brasil' strings and write it one more time, this one return UTF-8 too. Only the parameter $label has de ISO-8859-1 charset.

Comment: @Marc B, Headshot! I generally use Dreamweaver, but serching on Google i've found some tips to open the file using Notepad and save it as UTF-8 charset. I saw in Notepad that Dreamweaver was saving the file as ANSI and i think that this was generating the charset problem, because now the mb_detect_encoding() is detecting always UTF-8. Many thanks! =)