# php using utf8 without utf_encode

Tags: php, utf-8

i'm running a german website which gets content from a mysql database.
i've defined the charset as utf8 as following:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
```

the problem is, when fetching + displaying contents from the database i always need to use utf8_encode in order to get the proper german "umlauts".

i want to maintain the utf8 charset for my web as i'll have to add more languages which have special characters.

any ideas on how to 1:1 echo database contents without having to utf8_encode?

thanks

Comment: The common troubleshooting list: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing how you are connecting to your database, but a common problem is the database connection itself.

After opening / selecting the database you need to set:

```
$db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');    // PDO

mysql_set_charset('utf8');    // Deprecated mysql_* extension
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to use utf-8 with PHP and MySQL, I found that usually these two functions are the ones you should use after `mysql_connect()`:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8', $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content type in the header may do the trick:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solve adding this in the beginning of my PHP file:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Additionally, is very important to check if you are saving your PHP file in UTF-8 format without BOM, i had a big headache with this. I recomend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org), it shows the current file encoding and allow you to convert to UTF-8 without BOM if necessary.

If you would like to see my problem and solution, [it is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798596/function-parameter-with-strange-charset-behavior-in-php).

Hope it can help you!